# Xamarin выдает странные ошибки

Tags: xamarin

У меня с Xamarin Visual Studio творится что-то... в общем не слишком приятное. А именно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ничего не менял в проекте, в списке ошибок только предупреждения. Полазил по форумам - там написано, что надо обновить Xamarin. Как раз выскочило в правом нижнем углу, что можно обновить Xamarin. Попытался обновить, и что... Эта адская тварь выдала на последней секунде установки ошибку и снесла весь Xamarin. Я его три дня пытался скачать! Попытался установить Xamarin Studio - на компе лишь Profiler и WorkBooks.
Можете дать АКТУАЛЬНУЮ информацию по установке Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

Каким образом все устанавливали?
Пробуйте с помощью Средства->получить обновления и компоненты, там инсталируйте Xamarin.
А для более развернутых логов, в настройках студии поставьте галочки на все пункты, что бы в будущем, при сборке видеть не результат, а полный ход процесса что бы обнаружить неисправность.

Comment: Спасибо за своевременную помощь! Я уже всё сам решил))) На самом деле все проблемы решаются через NuGet, стабильный интернет и мощное устройство. Собственно вот и все...

Answer (score 0):

Я устанавливал 2017 студию с опциями для всяких XAMARIN и UNITY и еще много чего,с офф сайта XAMARIN-а, там инсталлер качаешь и выбираешь опции,у меня на одном компе нормально было,а на другом выдало ошибку,я перезапустил с правами админа,не знаю повлияло,нет,но щас установилось норм на второй комп,а конкретные ошибки пможно смотреть в логе устройства там где то правее сдк кнопочка вроде была,частые ошибки с настройками виртаулизации и различных ускорений.